# Git: How to fetch a single remote branch and create a remote-tracking branch of it automatically?

Tags: git

[git-fetch manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) says:

```
git fetch remote_repo
```

will update "remote-tracking branches" of all branches from the remote repository.

What if I only need fetch a single remote branch?

I try to run:

```
git fetch remote_repo remote_branch
```

It just stores infomation into `FETCH_HEAD` instead of creating a "remote-tracking branch" named `remote_repo/remote_branch`.

I know there is a solution:

```
git fetch remote_repo remote_branch:refs/remotes/remote_repo/remote_branch
```

But it's too verbose.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If the set of remote branches that you want to fetch is somewhat stable, you can edit `remote.<name>.fetch` with `git-config` to achieve that result:

```
git config remote.remote_repo.fetch remote_branch:refs/remotes/remote_repo/remote_branch
```

That config will be picked up as default when running a bare `git fetch`:

```
remote.<name>.fetch
    The default set of "refspec" for git-fetch(1). See git-fetch(1).
```