# Review a pull request locally before merging?

Tags: git, bitbucket

How do I review a bitbucket pull request through command line in my local machine before merging ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to fetch a single remote branch and create a remote-tracking branch of it automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019375/git-how-to-fetch-a-single-remote-branch-and-create-a-remote-tracking-branch-of)

Answer (score 0):

The merge itself takes place in Bitbucket, remotely, so the Bitbucket UI is the ideal place to be reviewing the pull request.  That being said, if you want to do some reviewing locally, the best thing might be for you to pull the branch in question.  After pulling, you can build and even test the feature branch.  In addition, with the branch on your local machine, you can also view a diff of every file which was changed.  An IDE with a Git plugin would be a good choice to view the diffs of files.

To pull the branch locally using the bash just use `git fetch origin` followed by `git checkout branch_to_review`.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. can you help me with the commands for pulling the branch.